# Will this anyhit shader ignore all hits?

Tags: raytracing

I am learning DXR (DirectX Raytracing), and have a very simple question as follows:

I am using Unity's HDRP RTX, and I have a simple "anyhit" shader as below:

```
[shader("anyhit")]
void AnyHit(inout RayPayload payload : SV_RayPayload, BuiltInTriangleIntersectionAttributes attribs : SV_IntersectionAttributes)
{
    IgnoreHit();
}
```

I thought it should ignore all hits, and thus no "closesthit" shader will be executed. However, I still see "closesthit" shader executed. The behavior is same even if I delete this "anyhit" shader totally. Why?

Comment: Please add some tags to your question. The question is not about general raytrace, but is specific to some platforms, frameworks, libraries.

Answer (score 0):

IgnoreHit only ends the current anyhit shader.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/any-hit-shader

To ignore closesthit shader, configure the flag to RAY_FLAG_SKIP_CLOSEST_HIT_SHADER in your TraceRay function.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/ray_flag